# Using Sql server with In

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have two tables Tbl_Event (primary key:-EventID) and tbl_items.

tbl_items table contains multiple items for same EventID with status 0 or 1.

Sample Data:

```
Tbl_event:
EventId  Name
5        Test
6        Seminar
7        Meet

tbl_items
ItemId    EventId  status 
1          5         0
2          6         1
2          6         0
3          7         1
3          7         1
```

I just need to get Event "Meet" having both status value 1.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Tbl_items L
INNER JOIN Tbl_Events E ON L.EventId = E.EventId 
WHERE      L.Eventid NOT IN (SELECT Eventid FROM TBL_VMS_LENT_ITEMS WHERE Status = 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean with event "meet"? Could be helpful to post your desired outcome.

Comment: You could add it to the `JOIN` conditions... `ON ... AND L.status = 1`

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: I need to remove multiple records.Above query returns multiple records with same eventId

Comment: Not clear.  You should post desired results.  An edit the question rather hand just answer in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a subquery which aggregates over events and checks that all statuses are 1:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EventId
    FROM tbl_items
    GROUP BY EventId
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)

SELECT t1.*
FROM Tbl_event t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.EventId = t2.EventId;
```

If you just want the event IDs, use `SELECT * FROM cte`, otherwise use the full query I gave immediately above.  This approach will generalize to more complex logic, should you need it later.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all events that have all items with status 1.

```
SELECT
    E.EventID
FROM
    Tbl_event AS E
    INNER JOIN tbl_items AS I ON E.EventID = I.EventID
GROUP BY
    E.EventID
HAVING
    MIN(I.status) = 1
```

If you want the full Event record:

```
;WITH EventsWithItemsStatus1 AS
(
    SELECT
        E.EventID
    FROM
        Tbl_event AS E
        INNER JOIN tbl_items AS I ON E.EventID = I.EventID
    GROUP BY
        E.EventID
    HAVING
        MIN(I.status) = 1
)
SELECT
    E.*
FROM
    Tbl_event AS E
    INNER JOIN EventsWithItemsStatus1 AS N ON E.EventID = N.EventID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` clause with `subquery`

```
select * from Tbl_event e
inner join (
      select EventId  
      from tbl_items
      where status = 1 
      group by EventId  
      having count(*) > 1 
) i on i.EventId  = e.EventId
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear

```
SELECT     min(L.ItemId), L.EventId
FROM       Tbl_items L
where      L.Status = 1 
group by   L.EventId
having count(*) > 1
```